# Creating leader lines for moved labels

Tags: qgis, labeling, symbology, geometry-generator, leader-line

With a lot of help from gis.stackexchange.com I've created leader lines for point symbols. The lines are based on a geometry generator symbology:

[Shortening line geometry using expression dialog in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227108/shortening-line-geometry-using-expression-dialog-in-qgis)

[image]

Now, I want to implement leader lines for moved labels. It's very importent to me, that the lines start at the center of the labels and end at the point coordinates (or vice versa).

```
-- Geometry generator:
make_line(
    make_point(label_x, label_y),
    $geometry)
```

Once again, the lines are covered by the labels:

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to address the label boxes and shorten the leader lines? I suppose this is quite a tricky question :/

Comment: Try changing the offset values

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 12):

Firstly, this is a really neat solution! I solved this using a database view (a bit of overkill, but it worked).

My suggestion is to use a background and fill on the label.

Or, [looking here](http://www.opengis.ch/2015/12/10/geometry-generator-symbology/), you may be able to chain together a buffer and clip type solution.

```
difference(make_line(make_point( "x" ,  "y" ), $geometry), buffer(make_point( "x" ,  "y" ),1))
```

I just tested the above, and it works (I have different fields than you, but it proves the point). The use of the geometry generator is really flexible, so you could have the buffer distance a field too, dependent on symbology perhaps?

I'm not sure what's happening with point 'three', but I guess the anchor point is off to the left a bit.

[image: disjoint label leader lines]

Comment: I've to do some tests in the next few days, but I'm afraid that a background will not work for complex projects without covering some layers.

Comment: Did you see the other part of my answer? I found something that will clip the leader lines for you @eclipsed_by_the_moon.

Comment: Clipping leader lines for fixed size symbols works fine, but labels are an issue. I'll try to calculate the buffer distance dynamically, as soon as I find some time.

Answer (score 4):

I currently work on a fork of easy custom labeling plugin, to enable automatic creation of label and linked header line.

Have a look at :
[EasycustomLabaling](https://github.com/patricev/EasyCustomLabeling)

Download it, unzip it, and paste the 'EasyCustomLabeling' repertory in the the repertory of your QGIS plugin repertory. Reload QGIS.

Comment: Your plugin is really useful, but I would prefer geometry generator created lines that start at the center of the labels.

Comment: I understand. For information, this can be set in the fields of the source layer when using this plugin (fields LblAlignV and LblAlignH) - Regards

Comment: Thx for the info, I'll test this at weekend.