# QGIS: Adjust line for labels at the feature end (Easy Custom Labeling)

Tags: qgis, labeling, symbology, style, geometry-generator

I work on a map of overlapping public transport fare areas, e.g., *Frankfurt(Oder) AB/BC*, which imply different fares for using the bus.

By utilising the Plugin *Easy Custom Labeling* I was able to create guiding lines between my custom labels and the features. However, some of the 'end points' of the lines (i.e., those inside the polygons) jeopardise the readability of the map. Each line ends at a feature's centroid (I guess), thereby causing confusion. Look at the image below, where it is unclear which area is labelled AB or BC, respectively:

[image: map example]

Is it possible to manually move the end point of each line? I imagine it like this:
[image: potential solution]

The question seems to be related to these:

- [Shortening line geometry using expression dialog in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227108/shortening-line-geometry-using-expression-dialog-in-qgis)
- [Creating leader lines for moved labels](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232709/creating-leader-lines-for-moved-labels)

I've fiddled around with the geometry generator, but I haven't found a solution.

I've already considered to derive a point layer that determines end points where they need to differ from centroids. Since the data are stored in a PostGIS environment, however, that might be a little unhandy to update when adapting to minor changes. We're talking about two maps of ~20 polygons each, for example:
[image: whole map example]

Comment: Hi, fluegelrad. Have you found any solution?

Comment: Nope. Just a dirty workaround that involves a separate point layer for the label positions, if I remember correctly... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯